# Angular: Automate login from inside of the app

Tags: angular

In an angular app(v12), we need to automate a login flow to validate the details.

On button click we need to open a new window with a URL(eg: twitter.com) and enter the username, password, domain values and click on the login button.

This automation can be done by using Selenium in an existing .net application.

I need some idea on how to achieve the same in angular application. There is no selenium driver available for angular.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.

Selenium is **a program** that manipulates **browser** from "outside" of it. Take it as a virtual keyboard and mouse of some kind. Angular is (at the end of build process) just a **javascript code** running **inside** of the browser. Code from one tab/window can't directly manipulate other tab/window.